I'm struggling to find the area of the region in the first quadrant bounded by the following curves. Any help?
Find the area of the region in the first quadrant bounded by the curves $x^2+y^2=1$, $y=xe^x$, and $x=ye^y$.

I've gathered that the intersection between $y=xe^x$ and $x^2+y^2=1$, which I've labeled $S_1$, is approximately $0.513489$, and the intersection between $x=ye^y$ and $x^2+y^2=1$, which I've labeled $S_2$, is approximately $0.858096409$.
I am pretty sure I will have to implement the Lambert W Function, but I am not sure how. Any help?

The region is symmetric about the line $y=x$, so you can probably avoid using $W$ if you compute the area of one of the white part in the 1st quadrant (using integration by parts, etc)
